# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'socketId')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

This is Messenger.jsx page

```
import "./messenger.css";
import Topbar from "../../components/topbar/Topbar";
import Conversation from "../../components/conversations/Conversation";
import Message from "../../components/message/Message";
import ChatOnline from "../../components/chatOnline/ChatOnline";
import { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "../../context/AuthContext";
import axios from "axios";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

export default function Messenger() {
  const [conversations, setConversations] = useState([]);
  const [currentChat, setCurrentChat] = useState(null);
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState("");
  const [arrivalMessage, setArrivalMessage] = useState(null);
  const [onlineUsers, setOnlineUsers] = useState([]);
  const socket = useRef();
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const scrollRef = useRef();

  const client = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8800/api" 
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current = io("ws://localhost:8900");
    socket.current.on("getMessage", (data) => {
      setArrivalMessage({
        sender: data.senderId,
        text: data.text,
        createdAt: Date.now(),
      });
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    arrivalMessage &&
      currentChat?.members.includes(arrivalMessage.sender) &&
      setMessages((prev) => [...prev, arrivalMessage]);
  }, [arrivalMessage, currentChat]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current.emit("addUser", user._id);
    socket.current.on("getUsers", (users) => {
      setOnlineUsers(
        user.followings.filter((f) => users.some((u) => u.userId === f))
      );
    });
  }, [user]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getConversations = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await client.get("/conversations/" + user._id);
        setConversations(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    getConversations();
  }, [user._id]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getMessages = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await client.get("/messages/" + currentChat?._id);
        setMessages(res.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    getMessages();
  }, [currentChat]);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const message = {
      sender: user._id,
      text: newMessage,
      conversationId: currentChat._id,
    };

    const receiverId = currentChat.members.find(
      (member) => member !== user._id
    );

    socket.current.emit("sendMessage", {
      senderId: user._id,
      receiverId,
      text: newMessage,
    });

    try {
      const res = await client.post("/messages", message);
      setMessages([...messages, res.data]);
      setNewMessage("");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollRef.current?.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }, [messages]);

  return (
    <>
      <Topbar />
      <div className="messenger">
        <div className="chatMenu">
          <div className="chatMenuWrapper">
            <input placeholder="Search for friends" className="chatMenuInput" />
            {conversations.map((c) => (
              <div onClick={() => setCurrentChat(c)}>
                <Conversation conversation={c} currentUser={user} />
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="chatBox">
          <div className="chatBoxWrapper">
            {currentChat ? (
              <>
                <div className="chatBoxTop">
                  {messages.map((m) => (
                    <div ref={scrollRef}>
                      <Message message={m} own={m.sender === user._id} />
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
                <div className="chatBoxBottom">
                  <textarea
                    className="chatMessageInput"
                    placeholder="write something..."
                    onChange={(e) => setNewMessage(e.target.value)}
                    value={newMessage}
                  ></textarea>
                  <button className="chatSubmitButton" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                    Send
                  </button>
                </div>
              </>
            ) : (
              <span className="noConversationText">
                Open a conversation to start a chat.
              </span>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="chatOnline">
          <div className="chatOnlineWrapper">
            <ChatOnline
              onlineUsers={onlineUsers}
              currentId={user._id}
              setCurrentChat={setCurrentChat}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

This is the error iam getting:
a user connected.
a user connected.
D:\MYPROJECTS\cfg\mern tutorials\chatapp\socket\index.js:35
io.to(user.socketId).emit("getMessage", {
^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'socketId')

I have created a node app to initiate socket. In the index.js file of socket-app i made all connections. Iam having socket error, it is saying socket app crashed.

index.js page:

```
const io = require("socket.io")(8900, {
    cors: {
      origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    },
  });
  
  let users = [];
  
  const addUser = (userId, socketId) => {
    !users.some((user) => user.userId === userId) &&
      users.push({ userId, socketId });
  };
  
  const removeUser = (socketId) => {
    users = users.filter((user) => user.socketId !== socketId);
  };
  
  const getUser = (userId) => {
    return users.find((user) => user.userId === userId);
  };
  
  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    //when ceonnect
    console.log("a user connected.");
  
    //take userId and socketId from user
    socket.on("addUser", (userId) => {
      addUser(userId, socket.id);
      io.emit("getUsers", users);
    });
  
    //send and get message
    socket.on("sendMessage", ({ senderId, receiverId, text }) => {
      const user = getUser(receiverId);
      io.to(user.socketId).emit("getMessage", {
        senderId,
        text,
      });
    });
  
    //when disconnect
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("a user disconnected!");
      removeUser(socket.id);
      io.emit("getUsers", users);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  from this  socket.on("sendMessage", ({ senderId, receiverId, text }) => {
      const user = getUser(receiverId);
      io.to(user.socketId).emit("getMessage", {
        senderId,
        text,
      });
    });

to
socket.on("sendMessage", ({ senderId, receiverId, text }) => {
      const user = getUser(receiverId);
      io.to(user?.socketId).emit("getMessage", {
        senderId,
        text,
      });
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).